# How can I create events in local calendar by Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to make an application. I want to add events to local calendar. But I don't know how to do that. It would be better if there were some simple examples.

Comment: You can use this plugin: https://pub.dev/packages/device_calendar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the plugin [add_2_calendar](https://pub.dev/packages/add_2_calendar).

#### Installation :

In your `pubspec.yaml` file within your Flutter Project:

```
dependencies:
  add_2_calendar: ^1.3.0
```

#### iOS integration :

In order to make this plugin work on iOS 10+, be sure to add this to your `info.plist` file:

```
<key>NSCalendarsUsageDescription</key>
<string>INSERT_REASON_HERE</string>
```

#### Usage :

```dart
import 'package:add_2_calendar/add_2_calendar.dart';

final Event event = Event(
      title: 'Event title',
      description: 'Event description',
      location: 'Event location',
      startDate: DateTime(/* Some date here */),
      endDate: DateTime(/* Some date here */),
    );
...
Add2Calendar.addEvent2Cal(event);
...
```

---

See also Flutter documentation for [using packages](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/using-packages). You can look for packages on [pub.dev](https://pub.dev) when you need to use device APIs.

Comment: Hey hi this does not support adding multiple event at a time, any  reference for that.

Comment: @SagarAcharya see https://pub.dev/packages/device_calendar

Comment: There is any ways to open "add calendar events" of local calendar with filled parameters instead of implementation of UI for it's fields?

Comment: Hi! how to configure custom days for an event

Comment: Does not work with Android API 30+ :-(