# How to parse ICalendar format in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, icalendar, dart-pub

I need to parse iCal format in Flutter and I don't find any package for do it. Someone can tell me if it exist any solution for solve my problem?

Comment: Did you get a solution to this? I am likely going to do it in the next couple of weeks but obviously would prefer to save some time. It would be ideal if it could be a Flutter plugin!

Comment: sorry no solution :/

Comment: if you find a solution ?

Comment: Not yet, but I am working on an implementation in my spare time.  I wouldn't hold your breath though :)

Comment: @brindy did you release your implementation as open source?

Comment: Nothing worth sharing tbh.  I just did something crude as a PoC.  The project was supposed to kick off properly in March but got canned because of Covid :(

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you still have your issue but I've just released a package to parse iCalendar format in pure dart.

https://pub.dev/packages/icalendar_parser

It is still in early development stage but might help you with your problem.

Here is an example on how you could use the package:

```dart
import 'package:icalendar_parser/icalendar_parser.dart';

// Parsing from an ICS String (ex: if you are getting data from an API)
final iCalParsed = ICalendar.fromString(yourIcsString);

// Parsing from an ICS List<String> (ex: if you are reading data from a file)
final iCalParsed2 = ICalendar.fromLines(icsFileLines);
```

Here is a full example I've made in Flutter:

```dart
import 'dart:core';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;
import 'package:icalendar_parser/icalendar_parser.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart' as p;

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  ICalendar _iCalendar;
  bool _isLoading = false;

  Future<void> _getAssetsFile(String assetName) async {
    setState(() => _isLoading = true);
    try {
      final directory = await getTemporaryDirectory();
      final path = p.join(directory.path, assetName);
      final data = await rootBundle.load('assets/$assetName');
      final bytes =
          data.buffer.asUint8List(data.offsetInBytes, data.lengthInBytes);
      final file = await File(path).writeAsBytes(bytes);
      final lines = await file.readAsLines();
      setState(() {
        _iCalendar = ICalendar.fromLines(lines);
        _isLoading = false;
      });
    } catch (e) {
      setState(() => _isLoading = false);
      throw 'Error: $e';
    }
  }

  Widget _generateTextContent() {
    final style = const TextStyle(color: Colors.black);
    return RichText(
      text: TextSpan(
        children: [
          TextSpan(
              text: 'VERSION: ${_iCalendar.version}\n',
              style: style.copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
          TextSpan(
              text: 'PRODID: ${_iCalendar.prodid}\n',
              style: style.copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
          TextSpan(
              children: _iCalendar.data
                  .map((e) => TextSpan(
                        children: e.keys
                            .map((f) => TextSpan(children: [
                                  TextSpan(
                                      text: '${f.toUpperCase()}: ',
                                      style: style.copyWith(
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                                  TextSpan(text: '${e[f]}\n')
                                ]))
                            .toList(),
                      ))
                  .toList()),
        ],
        style: style,
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            if (_isLoading || _iCalendar == null)
              const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
            else
              _generateTextContent(),
            RaisedButton(
              child: const Text('Load File 1'),
              onPressed: () => _getAssetsFile('calendar.ics'),
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              child: const Text('Load File 2'),
              onPressed: () => _getAssetsFile('calendar2.ics'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To parse/get each platform's calendar?

A quick search of https://pub.dev/packages?q=calendar shows some possible candidates:

- https://pub.dev/packages/add_2_calendar
- https://pub.dev/packages/ical_serializer
- https://pub.dev/packages/device_calendar
- https://pub.dev/packages/manage_calendar_events

Also other related stack posts:

- [Adding an event to a calendar from Flutter app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51910079/adding-an-event-to-a-calendar-from-flutter-app), this refers to `device_calendar` plugin
- [How can I create events in local calendar by Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57945937/how-can-i-create-events-in-local-calendar-by-flutter), this refers to `add_2_calendar` plugin

If you're not satisfied with the existing plugins, then yes, *don't hold your breath*, but get to work on your own through [custom platform-specific code](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels).